# Edit Mode in Android Listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, textview

I have a listview, in that there have Textview. And on the top I have an Edit Button 
when I press the edit button I want to show checkboxes for listview rows and one delete button at the bottom of screen for delete the list item also.

Any one can help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: check this tutorial using contextual menu http://www.miximum.fr/tutos/849-porting-the-contextual-anction-mode-for-pre-honeycomb-android-apps

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom list item having a TextView and a Checkbox to its right. Also, have a button at the parent bottom and set your listview as `layout_above` that button. Make sure that, the visibility of your Checkbox and Button is set to `View.GONE` by default. Now, on click of your `Edit` button, just set the visibility of Checkbox and Delete Button to `View.VISIBLE` and refresh your list. That's it. All the best!

Comment: Hi, I change my code as you said. But now I click the edit button the it shows one check box only that for first row.. any other methode? Thanks for help...

Comment: I said make a list item with a TextView and a Checkbox. So each of your list items will have the same format as of the first one.

Comment: Yes sir, I done it with that way .. 
     <TextView 
       />      
  
 <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text_number"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_number"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:text="" 
         android:visibility="gone"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your ListView with TextView as well as a CheckBox in each row. Hide the checkboxes by default and unhide them using the onClickListener for the Edit button.

I hope this helps.